# Iterate through an array of one class object and put those elements into an array belonging to another class object with Ruby.

Tags: ruby, arrays, class

Let's say I have two classes:

```
class One
  attr_reader :array
  def initialize(array)
    @array = array
  end
end

class Two < One
  attr_reader :array
  def initialize
    @array = []
  end
end
```

I now instantiate one object of class "One" and two objects from class "Two".

```
array = ["D","E"] 
a = One.new(array)
b = Two.new
c = Two.new
```

Is it possible to create a method situated inside the One class that accepts two arguments such that if the string exists in One @array, copy that element put that element in the array of a specified array belonging to Two class?

```
Example:

def place_string(element,location)
  if location == "b"
    take element, copy it and place it into @array in b
  elsif location == "c"
    take element, copy it and place it into @array in c
  end
end
a.place_string("D","b")
a.place_string("E","c")

Output:
  a.array = ["D","E"]
  b.array = ["D"]
  c.array = ["E"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class One
  attr_reader :array
  def initialize(array=[])
    @array = array
  end

  def copy(element, location)
    if array.include? element
      location.array << element
    end
  end
end

class Two < One
end

array = ["D","E"] 
a = One.new(array)
b = Two.new
c = Two.new

a.copy("D", b)
a.copy("NOT EXIST", b)
b.array
#=> ["D"]
```